# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preparse' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, momentjs

I am trying to display dates in jquery data tables and fetching the data through a sql stored procedure. I am seeing this error when trying to use moment.js to have the correct format of date to display date in the data tables.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mesa = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    filename: "LocationCodes",
    responsive: true,
    "bAutoWidth": false, // toggle this depending on how wide you want the table
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/controller/storedprocedure",
      "type": "GET",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "deferRender": true,
    "responsive": true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "bSort": false,
    buttons: ['excel', 'print'],
    "columns": [{
      "data": "FileName"
    }, {
      "data": "ProjectName"
    }, {
      "data": "RecordInsertTime",
      "sType": 'date'
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      targets: 2,
      render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('2017-08-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'en')
    }]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2566)? It suggests that you need to add the script reference for the locale you're using - `fr` in your case.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have seen this issue and not sure where to add the locale in my code

Comment: Go to https://momentjs.com/. At the bottom click 'French', now at the top download `moment-with-locales.min.js`

Comment: I have edited my question. It should be 'en' not 'fr'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan After editing now the error is gone but the date is not displayed and it says invalid date on the data tables

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the question's comments, for those who wants to use the `locale` parameter in `$.fn.dataTable.render.moment()`, you need to load the file *moment-with-locales.js* instead of *moment.js*.

For example with a CDN (placed before DataTables):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```